# Reference classical proof of the statement: there are 27 lines on a cubic surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm taking an introduction course on Algebraic Geometry at the moment and want to know more about the 27 lines on a cubic surface, which is also known as the Cayley–Salmon theorem. However most proofs I can find on the internet use a modern approach to the problem. This approach makes use of the concepts divisors and schemes which are new concepts and quite difficult to me. Therefore it would be more accessible for me to find the more classical approach to this problem. Can someone recommend me a good reference for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know three sources for an elementary proof of *27 lines theorem*:

1. A. Gathmann - *[Algebraic Geometry](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf)* (2014) Chapter 11;
2. K. Hulek - *Elementary Algebraic Geometry* (2003) A.M.S. Chapter 5;
3. M. Manetti - *[Geometria Algebrica](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/manetti/dispense/GeoAlgebrica(23dicembre2015).pdf)* (2015) Capitolo 11 (in Italian).